# How can I know when my almonds are ready to eat?

Tags: almond

[image: Almond pods]

The tree itself is about 3 years old and this is the first time it's bearing produce.

I can see the pods which contain the almonds. Is there any way to tell when they will be ready/fit for consumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When most of the drupes or almonds split is when you pick, although you can leave them on the tree longer, but then other creatures may take and eat them. Note ripening takes place from the top of the tree down, so if you have animals (squirrels in some countries) that might pick and eat them, you will need to keep an eye on the ripening process so as not to have them all taken. More info here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/nut-trees/almonds/when-to-harvest-almonds.htm